# where can I read about layout changes in android key lime pie?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I ran my android widget which I have wrote

on android Kit-kat and everything works fine.

I want t make sure it seems the same on Android [key lime pie](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/1308097/google-android-5-0-release-date-screenshots-features-news-and-rumours).

I want to read about what changes to layout are there in the new version.

I guess there are pre-release notes or beta version for developers to get ready for it and adjust their apps.

but have found no documentation about this.

Anyone saw such a thing?

Comment: There's no such thing as Android KeyLime Pie.

Comment: http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/1308097/google-android-5-0-release-date-screenshots-features-news-and-rumours

Comment: It was never released officially.The latest one available is [KitKat](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html). Have you installed it using a custom ROM ? Where did you get it from ?

Comment: from the link you sent: "Google was expected to call Android 4.4 Key Lime Pie, but a tie-in with Nestle saw version 4.4 go by KitKat instead.". Ergo: there's no such thing as Android KeyLimePie